# Sorted scatter plot differs from unsorted one

Tags: python, sorting, matplotlib, scatter-plot

It does make sense to me that a `plt.plot` needs to be sorted, however a scatter plot (`plt.scatter`) needing to be sorted seems weird. I encountered this issue with this script. The script itself does not matter and only serves as a minimal working example. What matters is the behavior of `scatter`, namely `plt.scatter(sorted(l2), Y)` will give a different result from `plt.scatter(l2, Y)`. Why is that? Makes no sense to me.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from math import log, exp, isnan
from sys import argv
from random import randint

def generate_linear_regression_line(X, Y):
    X_ = np.mean(X)
    XX_ = np.mean(map(lambda x:x*x,X))
    Y_ = np.mean(Y)
    XY_ = map(lambda x,y:x*y,X,Y)
    m = np.mean((X_ * Y_ - XY_) / (X_**2 - XX_))
    b = Y_ - m * X_
    print m
    print b
    return lambda x : m * x + b

max = int(argv[1])

l1 = [randint(1, max) for i in range(max)]
# l2 = range(0,max)
l2 = []
maxentry = 0
while len(l2) != max:
    n = randint(max, 2*max)
    if n not in l2:
        if n > maxentry:
            maxentry = n
        l2.append(n)
assert(maxentry >= len(l1))

assert(len(l2) == len(l1))


regl = generate_linear_regression_line(l2, l1)

X = []
Y = []
for i in range(len(l2)):
    X.append(i)
    Y.append(regl(i))

print sum(l1)
print sum(Y)

assert(len(Y) == len(l1))
# assert(sum(Y) > sum(l1))

plt.scatter(l2, l1)
plt.plot(X, Y, c='red')
plt.scatter(sorted(l2), Y, c='green')
plt.xlabel('L2')
plt.ylabel('L1')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the values in `Y` are dependent on the order of the values in `L2`, for example, `(L2[0], Y[0])` represents a point.  When you sort `L2` you reorder `L2` without reordering `Y`.

You could zip the two arrays, sort them and the make a scatter plot, for example:

```
import itertools
P = sorted(itertools.izip(L2, Y))
L2s, Ys = zip(*P)
plt.scatter(L2s, Ys, c='green')
```